# How can I autocomplete formula that can change column name when dragged down?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to set formula on a row basis that takes value from columns in LibreOffice. For example, I have values as shown below in Sheet 1:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
1   A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1  I1
2   A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2  G2  H2  I2
3   A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  F3  G3  H3  I3
```

In Sheet2, I need the values of each column in Sheet1 as row entries (as =Sheet1.A1) as shown below:

```
=Sheet1.A1
=Sheet1.B1
=Sheet1.C1
=Sheet1.D1
=Sheet1.E1
=Sheet1.F1
=Sheet1.G1
=Sheet1.H1
=Sheet1.I1
```

I should be able to complete the cells when I drag down the small square to get this pattern.

How can this be done in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [**`TRANSPOSE()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_TRANSPOSE_function) function as [array function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays):

1. Put the cursor into cell `Sheet2.A1`;
2. As formula, enter

   `=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1.A1:I1)`
3. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, to enter the formula as [array function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays).

Result:

[image]

To edit the formula afterwards, you'll have to select the complete resulting array (`Sheet2.A1:A9`) first. Otherwise, LO Calc will complain about changing only a part of an array.